# Example of '$g$' which is not a metric on $S^2$.

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I am trying to find out a non-degenerate, positive, bilinear form defined for every point $p$ in $S^2$, such that it is not a metric and illustrate the same (i.e. it must not be satisfying the smoothly varying criterion). Need an explicit example.

Then a further question would be :

i) How do I check if such a randomly given '$g$' will not be a Riemannian metric on a sphere ?

---

One direction of thought is : Let 'g' be a metric on a smooth manifold 'M' (here $S^2$), by the existence of a metric on a smooth manifold. Now consider for our case a chart $(U,\phi)$, and try with :

$$ \tilde{g} = (1 + \chi_U)g $$ This should be an example as on the boundary of $U$ it will not be smooth, but how do I explicitly show it in computation taking some particular vector fields ?

Comment: Start with something easier, like doing the same problem on an open interval instead of the circle and take the same construction you have. Can you think of a vector field that proves that $\tilde g$ is not Riemannian in this case? If it helps, take $g=dx^2$.

Comment: But I wanted  it on an object of non-zero curvature. So I want to avoid the interval case which is again the Euclidean case.

Comment: The point of my comment is to point you in the right direction towards the proof that the formula you have is not a Riemannian metric. If you understand how to do it in my example, there is a very good chance, you will see how it works with your formula.